# On the curve $Z(y^2 +x^3-x^2)$, at which point the rational function $\frac{y}{x}$ is regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> On the curve $ C= Z(y^2 +x^3-x^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$, at which point the rational function $\frac{y}{x}$ is regular?

And the second part of this question is

> Show that this function is not regular at every point of the curve.

I am confused by this question, we see that $C\cap \mathbb{A}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is an open set on this curve which the rational function $\frac{y}{x}$ is regular at each point of this open set. The only point that this function might not be regular is at $(0,0)$. Is there a typo?

And at $(0,0)$, from $y^2+x^3-x^2=0$, we have $\frac{y^2}{x^2} = x-1$, will this some how show that the function $\frac{y}{x}$ is also regular $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no typo.
 The exercise states (a bit clumsily) that the rational function $\phi(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}$ is regular at all points of $C$ different from $O=(0,0)$, but that it is not regular at $O$.
Since the first part is clear to you, I'll just show the second part.

If $\phi$ were regular at $O$, it would be regular on all of $C$ and we would have $\phi(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}=u(x,y) $ for some $u(x,y)\in \mathcal O(C)=k[x,y]=k[X,Y]/\langle Y^2+X^3-X^2\rangle$.
The equality $\frac{y}{x}=u(x,y) $ means that there exists a polynomial $w(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$ for which we have $$Y-Xu(X,Y)=(Y^2+X^3-X^2)\cdot w(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$$  But this is impossible because all monomials appearing in $(Y^2+X^3-X^2)\cdot w(X,Y)$ have degree at least $2$ while the polynomial $Y-Xu(X,Y)$ contains a monomial of degree one, namely $Y$.
This contradiction shows that actually $\phi$ is **not** regular at $O$.